# Unweighted-Single-Source-Shortest-Path using BFS in python

Tags: python, shortest-path, breadth-first-search

Im new at python. I try to get the Unweighted-Single-Source-Shortest-Path using BFS.

```
from queue import *


def ussp(graph, s):
    len_graph = len(graph)
    prev = [[]*len_graph for i in range(len_graph)]
    visited = [False for i in range(len_graph)]
    queue2 = Queue
    dist = [[float('inf')] for i in range(len_graph)]
    queue2.put_nowait(graph[s], 0)  # starting with s
    visited[s] = True
    dist[s] = 0

    # modified BFS alg.
    while queue2.empty() == False:
        h = queue2.get_nowait()
        for i in len(graph[h]):
            if visited[graph[h][i]] == False:
                visited[graph[h][i]] = True
                dist[graph[h][i]] = dist[h] + 1
                prev[graph[h][i]] = h
                queue2.put_nowait(graph[h][i], 0)
    print(dist)


graph2 = {1: [2, 3, 5], 2: [4, 6, 1], 3: [5, 1], 4: [6], 5: [2], 6: [1, 7], 7: [2]}
ussp(graph2, 1)
```

Thats what I got for now. I was pretty sure it should work, but it does not at all. It doesn't even get compiled. Im pretty new with lists, arrays and queues in python, too. Would be kind if you could help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Two things: first, it's considered bad practice to ever use `from <package> import *` in Python because it makes debugging really hard. Second, on SO it's helpful to post your traceback/error message so that people can see what's wrong.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Of course. Here are the errors:                                                           `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/svenp/PycharmProjects/or3/or4.py", line 27, in <module>
    ussp(graph2, 1)
  File "C:/Users/svenp/PycharmProjects/or3/or4.py", line 10, in ussp
    queue2.put_nowait(graph[s], 0)  # starting with s
  File "C:\Users\svenp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\queue.py", line 184, in put_nowait
    return self.put(item, block=False)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'put' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I added in a destination parameter to your function signature. Assuming you wanted to find the shortest path from node 1 to node 7, the program below works. 
I also added some python boilerplate since you said you are new to python.

```
import sys
from queue import Queue as Q

def ussp(graph, s, d):
    len_graph = len(graph)

    prev = [ -1 for i in range(len_graph)]
    visited = [False for i in range(len_graph)]
    q = Q()
    dist = [sys.maxsize for i in range(len_graph)]
    q.put(s, False)
    visited[s-1] = True
    dist[s-1] = 0

    # modified BFS alg.
    while q.empty() == False:
        h = q.get_nowait()
        for i in range(len(graph[h])):
            if visited[graph[h][i]-1] == False:
                visited[graph[h][i]-1] = True
                dist[graph[h][i]-1] = dist[h-1] + 1
                prev[graph[h][i]-1] = h
                q.put_nowait(graph[h][i])

    path = []
    crawl = d # destination
    path.append(crawl)
    while (prev[crawl-1] != -1):
        path.append(prev[crawl-1])
        crawl = prev[crawl-1]

    print(list(reversed(path)))


def main():
    graph2 = {1: [2, 3, 5], 2: [4, 6, 1], 3: [5, 1], 4: [6], 5: [2], 6: [1, 7], 7: [2]}
    ussp(graph2, 1, 7)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is the cause of your error:

```
queue2 = Queue
```

You're setting `queue2` equal to the `Queue` class, instead of an instance of the `Queue` class.

Change that line to this:

```
queue2 = Queue()
```